# dojo how to query node that has been removed from DOM

Tags: dom, dojo

From my testing, it appears that dojo's `query()` function only selects from among elements that are part of a page's DOM.

For example, suppose I have a node named `rootNode` that has some number of descendents with the class `someClass`.  This code:

`var nodeList = query(".someclass", rootNode);`

will return an empty NodeList if `rootNode` has been removed from the DOM (but, of course, if `rootNode` is part of the DOM, it will return all the nodes with class `someClass`.

**My question: is there a way to use `query()` in this situation?**  If not, what is the preferred way for handling this?  It looks to me like some of NodeList's methods can be used with a filter(remove and place), but that's not quite the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear.  I have a div that I have removed from a page's DOM but have kept a reference to.  Later on, I want to query that div to find some of its descendents that match particular criteria and then do something with those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer turned out to be very simple: although I didn't find it in the documentation, you can simply call `query()` on a NodeList.  e.g.

```
var nodeList = query.NodeList();
nodeList.push(rootNode);
var results = nodeList.query(yourSelector);
```

Note, however: if `yourSelector` is a unique id and `rootNode` has been removed from the DOM, it doesn't appear to work.  Other types of selectors (class, children, etc) seem to work.  I wonder if that's a bug in Dojo...

Answer (score 1):

You can get a dojo **`NodeList`** as the return result of your `dojo.query`.  Then you can use `nodes.map` or `nodes.every` to find the elements you want.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList.html

Comment: Thanks - yes, this is doable but not quite the same as using `query` when one is not interested just in the nodes in the NodeList but rather in them and all of their children as well.

Comment: I'll leave this answer here since it was the assist for your slam dunk.  :)  Maybe someone else who stumbles across this would find it useful.